# How can I rank turtle, according to their attribute? in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I built a model that each turtle has their own strategy, and they will earn money according to their strategy.
Therefore, Turtles will own money, and strategy.
I want to rank top10 turtles who has the most money, and want to see which strategy that they have.
Is there any way that I can show it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [max-n-of](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#max-n-of) to get the top 10 agents and ask them about their strategy.

Something like

```
ask max-n-of 10 turtles [money] [show strategy]
```

To sort the result use `sort-on`:

```
foreach sort-on [(- money)] max-n-of 10 turtles [money] 
  [  ask ? [ show strategy ] ]
```